# How can I block a Controller function from being used if ids do not match?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have two tables in my database: 'users' and 'bookings'. In the bookings table, a column exists that contains the id (foreign key) of the user that created the booking. My goal is to be able to cross-check this id (in the bookings table) with that of the id of the person who is logged in. (Perhaps using `Auth::user();`, please confirm) Essentially only allowing them to update bookings that they have created, but not bookings belonging to other users. (So a one to many relationship). 
 Is there any way to encapsulate the function in the Controller I am using with a check to verify the id? Here is my eventController.php:

```
    public function update(Request $request, Booking $booking)
    {
        $booking = Booking::where('created_by', auth('api')->user()->id)->findOrFail($id);

            $booking->start_date = $request->start_date;
            $booking->end_date = $request->end_date;
            $booking->resourceId = $request->resourceIds;
            $booking->save();
            return $booking;
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::apiResource('/bookings', eventController::class);
```

The reason why I am trying to figure out a method to encapsulate this is that I would prefer not to compare values in public JS, where security issues are posed.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... perhaps the [Laravel 8.x - Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization) documentation will help, especially the [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#creating-policies) sections.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can confirm, for example:

```
if(Auth::id() == $booking->user_id){
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using it: https://imgur.com/v1qsK4W. But upon testing it seems like it completely ignores the if statement, carrying it out anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are using Passport for authentication and your `api.php` routes since you are consuming your endpoint from JS.
IMO, the best choices here are:

1. [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding).

You can restrict the method by checking the model bound to the route only for the creator (explicit binding). If binding fails, a 404 will be thrown unless you [customize your missing model behavior](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-missing-model-behavior).

api.php

```
Route::patch('/bookings/{booking:id}', [BookingController::class, 'update']);
```

RouteServiceProvider.php (`boot()` method)

```
$this->bind('booking', function ($value) {
     return Booking::where('created_by', auth('api')->user()->id)->findOrFail($value);
});
```

2. Within your controller by throwing an exception

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   $booking = Booking::where('created_by', auth('api')->user()->id)->findOrFail($id);
   ...
}
```

Or in case you are using implicit binding model in your route

```
public function update(Request $request, $booking )
{
   if ($booking->created_by != auth('api')->user()->id) {
      abort(404, "You don't own this booking!");
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have tried your option 2 where I am using implicit binding. However it is reporting that `Auth guard [api] is not defined`, further research does not seem to provide any reason for this. Any ideas? I have also updated my code above along with my Routing in api.php